Going from percent exceedance over period of X g PGA to probability of event at Y g PGA
The seismic hazard map I can find are set at given return period, showing what PGA value is expected to be exceeded. Does the opposite exist? Maps with a given PGA value that show the expected return period? If it does not exist as such, say I have a map of the PGA values with a 10% exceedance over 50 years. Can I approximate the corresponding likelihood of events at different PGA values?
For example:
A location has a 10% exceedance likelihood over 50 years for PGA = 0.23g. Based on this, can I roughly approximate the yearly likelihood that it sees a 0.34g event? Or a 0.45g? etc.
I suppose it doesn't obviously perfectly fit, and likely varies by location anyway, but there might be a way to estimate empirically that has been developed? Any reference would be greatly appreciated!
